# Video making software for Android Tablet

Tags: android, video, tablet

I wanted to make  video demo of my application in order to present. How can i make my application video when it running and open on android Tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to come up with ways to do this to no avail. Best I've ever been able to achieve is stick your device in front of a nice camera.

However this http://www.bluestacks.com/ seems like it might be promising for this purpose once it is released. If you can run your apps on a windows machine (and it is much better than the emulator) then you could record that section of your screen with something like Fraps.

Edit: Bluestacks has since opened up for beta. For me it runs similarly to the emulator so does not provide a whole lot of benefit for the purposes of recording your applications. If you don't have a development environment with an emulator set up already though bluestacks will be ready for you to actually start recording quicker.